# how to perform search on Hiragana data in objective c

Tags: ios, search, localization

I'm trying to search through contacts using `UISearchBar`. I want my app to also support Japanese, but when the search includes any Japanese, the search fails.

I've tried this [How to perform searching based on characters starting in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783157/how-to-perform-searching-based-on-characters-starting-in-ios) but didn't have any luck.

Basically I want to perform Hiragana based (or, in other words, non latin alphabet character) searching in my app.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more clear on what you mean by the search failing?  Does it return no results, or does it crash in some way?

Comment: It doesn't crash. It returns no results. 
person.phoneticFullName myContainsString:searchText

Comment: Japanese search is one of the hardest. You need more than literal search. You need homonym search and well it's one of the hardest to tokenize.

Comment: Are you writing in Obj-C or in Swift?  For purely Hiragana entries, I had luck using `str.rangeOfString(substring)` in Swift.  Of course, as @uchuugaka mentioned, tokenizing and accounting for homonyms is another issue.  If you have your phone set to Japanese, it does allow you to have a reading for a name, but I'm not sure how that's accessed.

Comment: It's done by common names in built in dictionaries as well as by the phonetic name fields in your contacts if any. Uncommon names and names in general are some of the toughest. Kanji and word boundaries in Japanese are non deterministic in lots of common scenarios. Open source MeCab C library is a great tokenizer but input methods are not open APIs.

Comment: I've done this using identifying hiragana and Katakana  characters. I've also used NSPredicate with CONTAINS .
Thanks all for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this using identifying hiragana and Katakana characters. I've also used NSPredicate with CONTAINS .